# std::nth_element causes segfault; am I missing something, or a bug in STL?

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault

I encountered a strange segfault in a big project; finally I managed to locate the code and dump the data. Here is a simplified program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const float DATA[] = {
    0.179697, -0.413853, -0.079650, 0.167255, -1.263407, 1.707440, -0.162176,
    -0.176349, -0.826179, -0.097582, -0.265471, 0.070675, 0.077035, -0.218272,
    -0.509723, -0.244462, 0.000000, -0.069970, -0.169399, 0.236123, -1.063037,
    0.048428, 0.080877, -0.099672, -0.580204, -0.174694, -0.082321, -0.313485,
    1.828802, -0.110842, -0.367741, 0.026412, 0.116269, -0.164420, -0.726286,
    -0.335257, 0.456737, -0.465721, -0.242003, -0.755520, -1.155553, 0.013372,
    -0.033874, -0.105618, 0.000000, -0.578532, -0.057074, 0.026309, -0.978317,
    -0.253747
};

int main() {
    std::vector<float> arr(DATA, DATA + sizeof(DATA) / sizeof(DATA[0]));

    /*
    for (std::vector<float>::iterator i = arr.begin();
            i != arr.end(); i ++)
        *i = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
        */

    // std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + 1, arr.end());
    std::nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.end() - 1, arr.end());
    cout << arr.back() << endl;
}
```

Thanks for reading up here! The problem is that this program, if supplied with this data, would segfault on my machine (if it works on your machine, you can try running it with valgrind) ; However, if I uncomment any of those commented two blocks (i.e. use random data, or first sort the array), the program would run as expected.

I have tried with clang 3.3 and gcc 4.8.2, compiling with/without -O2, under c++03/c++11; it's always the same. I use archlinux, x64, libstdc++5 3.3.6.

Thanks very much for your kind help :)

segfault backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000000000401a9f in std::__unguarded_partition<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, float> (
    __first=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x625000>, __last=1.89120642e-40, __pivot=@0x6040c8: 1.82880199)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2242
#1  0x0000000000401497 in std::__unguarded_partition_pivot<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > > (__first=1.82880199, 
    __last=1.89120642e-40) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2283
#2  0x0000000000401134 in std::__introselect<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, long> (__first=1.82880199, 
    __nth=0.236122996, __last=1.89120642e-40, __depth_limit=7) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2365
#3  0x0000000000400e48 in std::nth_element<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > > (__first=-0.174694002, __nth=0.236122996, 
    __last=1.89120642e-40) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:5377
#4  0x0000000000400b2c in main () at tnew.cc:29
```

**edit**: for archlinux, downgrading to gcc 4.8.1-3 solves the problem (sudo pacman -Ud /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gcc-multilib-4.8.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz)

Comment: You do know that `arr.begin() + SIZE - 1` would be the same as `arr.end() - 1`? (If you read `SIZE` values, that is.)

Comment: Are you sure you actually *read* `SIZE` elements from the file? There's no error checking.

Comment: Where exactly your program crash and what stack trace shows?

Comment: @Slava Please see the new edit :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your advice, I have changed the code:) Still segfault ...

Comment: To isolate problems like this, remove the file input and stuff hard-coded values into the vector. That will help you figure out whether the problem is in the data or in the code that manipulates it. And it will make it much easier for folks online to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker At first I fear that embedding floating point literally would change their values; now I've updated the code, which is much more clear. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Your newest code works fine over on ideone: http://ideone.com/nysRUp

Comment: Works for me, gcc 4.2.1, gcc 4.7.0, gcc 4.8.1, clang 4.2.

Comment: SEGFAULT on g++4.8.1 and clang++3.4, libstdc++4.8.1

Comment: So this seems to be a bug introduced since some version of g++? But I really need c++11 Any solutions? Maybe it's better to implement my own nth_element.

Comment: Works for me, g++ 4.7.2, linux 64 bit, clang 3.4 trunk.

Comment: Works for me on GCC 4.7.3 and clang 3.4 (Ubuntu 13.04 x64).

Comment: @jiakai Not sure why it fails with g++ 4.8.1 (as reported by you and other members). However, instead of std::nth_element, you can try 'boost::nth_element' before implementing your own algorithm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to hit this [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58800) so you should update libstdc++ at least to 4.8.3

Comment: segfault still in g++4.9 2013-10-15; I'm updating it now to see if it has been resolved for this case.

Comment: libstdc++ is included in the svn repo of gcc. I should have said that I'm compiling both from trunk.

Comment: @DyP last comment there about fix published 2013-10-20

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm compiling it right now to see if it has been fixed ;)

Comment: No segfault in gcc/g++4.9 2013-10-22 (including updated libstdc++); problem has indeed been fixed.